# Forge - Upload multiple 3d files to a project so that I can see all of them combined on the viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I need to upload multiple 3d files, and see them combined in one viewer. I am using this library

> "forge-apis": "^0.9.2"

I know this is possible but I haven't found anything in the documentation about that. I know that using model derivative I can combine files but that is in the case I am uploading in chunks.

An example to upload would be:

```
MAIN-FOLDER/
  some-file.rvt
  CAD/
    file1.pdf
    file2.pdf
  PDF/
    file1.pdf
    file2.pdf
  TEXTURES/
    file1.jpg
    file2.jpg
```

So, how could I approach this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can (and in this case, should) upload and translate the files individually. Later, you can load (or "aggregate") them all into a single viewer instance. You can find more details about the aggregation in viewer on our blog, for example:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/aggregate-multi-models-sequence-forge-viewer
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher

Btw. there's also an option to upload and translate multiple files in a single ZIP archive, however this is typically only used in situations where multiple design files are referencing each other.

Comment: Thanks!. Also, if I have for instance a rvt file and jpg and pdf files to upload, how can approach that. I did it in a zip file, but doesn't seem to be working. (Not reading the jpg and pdf files)